# How can I join tables during load in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have already loaded the data to their stage and I want to join these together but it seems I cannot perform the `join` statement within the pipe.

This is my code:

```sql
create or replace pipe publictransportation.public.busstop_pipe
as
copy into publictransportation.public.DIM_BUSSTOP
from (
  select bsr.$1, bsr.$2,bsr.$3, bsr.$4, bsr.$5, bsr.$6
  from 
  (
    select bs.$1, bs.$2, bs.$3, bs.$4, sr.$2, sr.$3
    from @publictransportation.public.busstop_stage bs
    join @publictransportation.public.stoproute_stage sr
    on bs.$1 = sr.$1
  ) bsr
)
file_format = csv_format;
```

My code is simply to select some columns in each table and join them together to make a `DIM_BUSSTOP` table.

The error I got is:

```
SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.
```

How can I perform `join` and load it to the `DIM_BUSSTOP` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html), COPY transformations do not support the JOIN syntax (although they do also say the list of supported functions might expand over time).

So you'll need to create *two* PIPEs into two different database tables, and then perform the join to create `DIM_BUSSTOP` using ordinary SQL inside Snowflake.